# Correct way to easily call function with web3j from deployed contract

Tags: go-ethereum, dapps, web3j, cryptography

I am trying to call a function from a modified ERC20 contract and I can't manage to make it work. I am doing this with web3j from Android.

I can connect to Infura. The contract is already deployed on Rinkeby. I checked everything and the address is good. I'm trying to create credentials from a private/public key pair and pass it to use gas from that account.

```
String publicKey = "0x1900a41f2777ab70aad2074e3F4B9c5429c7f243";
    String privateKey = "some private key";
    String sparkTokenAddr = "some_addr";

    Credentials creds = Credentials.create(privateKey, publicKey);

    SparkToken spark = SparkToken.load(
            sparkTokenAddr, web3, creds, ManagedTransaction.GAS_PRICE, Contract.GAS_LIMIT);

    try {

        TransactionReceipt transactionReceipt = spark.chargedPhone(
                BigInteger.valueOf(50), publicKey).send();

        Log.e("ethereum", String.valueOf(transactionReceipt));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("ethereum", "Could not send tx");
    }
```

It always logs that the tx could not be sent. What do I do wrong?

Comment: What's the exception?

Answer (score 0):

This is the code template I generally use to call functions in my smart contract

```
    contractName.FunctionINeedToCall(function(error, result) {
       if (!error) {
           //Things I want to carry out if there's no error
           console.log(result)
       } else {
            console.log(error);
        }

   });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your RPC provider has a problem. Do you see any numbers in your "request today" section in infura ? If not,at first change your API method to "websockets" (or "https" if websockets selected before) after that, we have to check other sections of the contract or js.